# Azure Service Fabric REST API - how to copy application package to image store?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am looking for Service Fabric REST API method for copying an application package to the image store of a service fabric cluster. That is, method similar to Power Shell cmdlet [Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/copy-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps) and Service Fabric Client .NET API method [FabricClient.ApplicationManagementClient.CopyApplicationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.applicationmanagementclient.copyapplicationpackage?view=azure-dotnet).

I can't find such a method from [Service Fabric Client REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index).

How similar operation should be done using Service Fabric REST API methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK both `CopyApplicationPackage` and `Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage` use [ImageStore API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index-imagestore) under the hood, so I think ImageStore [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index#imagestore-apissfclient-index-imagestoremd) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, this is the case. More details in separate answer.

Comment: this answer adds nothing that wasn't already in the question

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I can't find a link to ImageStore REST API in the question but if you think posting a link to requested information deserves a downvote - I accept this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to copy the manifest files using ImageStore REST API method [Upload File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-uploadfile). In this case only the manifest files are uploaded as they define Azure Container Registry location where container packages are stored. After manifest files were loaded to ImageStore, I succeeded to [Provision Application Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-provisionapplicationtype) to Service Fabric Cluster.

Details that caused me some head-ache:

1. Upload File: manifest files were uploaded to image store into a folder with subfolders. An empty file '_.dir' needed to be uploaded into each folder; this is a mark file used by image store service internally to indicate the availability of the linked folder. See API reference and GitHub discussion '[Provisioning application type throws exception](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/363)'.
2. Image Store contents can be checked with REST API method [Get Image Store Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-getimagestorecontent). Anyhow, the uploaded files are not visible via this method until application type is provisioned.
3. If you [Provision Application Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-provisionapplicationtype) using 'ImageStorePath' option, the value given to body parameter [ApplicationTypeBuildPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-model-provisionapplicationtypedescription#applicationtypebuildpath) is **relative** to 'fabric:ImageStore'. I spent some quality time using 'fabric:ImageStore/MyAppType' until I realized to fix this to 'MyAppType'.